# Looping through a json file in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Having looked through several examples on SO, I cannot find a close enough example with a similar data structure. I have the data structure below. I am looking to extract the values for the following keys in the `vnetArray`

- vNetName
- subnetName
- SubnetAddressSpace
- serviceEndpoints
- securityRules
- routes

For the subnetArray. I am looking to extract the following fields

- vNetName
- subnetName
- SubnetAddressSpace
- serviceEndpoints
- securityRules
- routes
- delegations

Following some of the examples I saw, I have written the below which does not work.

```
$a = Get-Content '.\json_file.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($record in $a)
{
        write-host "$($record.vNetArray.vNetName) | $($record.vNetArray.vNetLocation) | $($record.vNetArray.NetworkType) | $($record.vNetArray.vNetAddressSpace)"
}
```

json_file.json

```
{
    "$Schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "$contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "vNetArray": {
        "value": [
          {
            "vNetName": "vnet-test-cus-stg",
            "vNetLocation": "CentralUS",
            "NetworkType": "Spoke",
            "vNetAddressSpace": "10.1.0.0/16",
            "subnets": [
              {
                "vNetName": "vnet-test-cus-stg",
                "subnetName": "snet-webapp-cus-stg",
                "SubnetAddressSpace": "10.1.1.0/25",
                "serviceEndpoints": [],
                "securityRules": [],
                "routes": []
              },
             {
                "vNetName": "vnet-test-cus-stg",
                "subnetName": "snet-agw-cus-stg",
                "SubnetAddressSpace": "10.1.3.0/25",
                "serviceEndpoints": [],
                "securityRules": [],
                "routes": []
              },
              {
                "vNetName": "vnet-test-cus-stg",
                "subnetName": "snet-sql-cus-stg",
                "SubnetAddressSpace": "10.1.4.0/25",
                "serviceEndpoints": [],
                "securityRules": [],
                "routes": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "subnetArray": {
        "value": [
          {
            "vNetName": "vnet-test-cus-stg",
            "subnetName": "snet-webapp-cus-stg",
            "SubnetAddressSpace": "10.1.1.0/25",
            "serviceEndpoints": [],
            "securityRules": [],
            "routes": [],
            "delegations":[
              {
                  "name": "Microsoft.Web.serverFarms",
                  "properties": {
                      "serviceName": "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
                  }
              } 
          ],
          "PSDelegation": "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"       
          },
          {
            "vNetName": "vnet-test-cus-stg",
            "subnetName": "snet-agw-cus-stg",
            "SubnetAddressSpace": "10.1.3.0/25",
            "serviceEndpoints": [],
            "securityRules": [],
            "routes": [],
            "delegations":[],
            "PSDelegation": ""                   
          },
          {
            "vNetName": "vnet-test-cus-stg",
            "subnetName": "snet-sql-cus-stg",
            "SubnetAddressSpace": "10.1.4.0/25",
            "serviceEndpoints": [
              {
                "service": "Microsoft.sql"
              }
            ],
            "securityRules": [],
            "routes": [],
            "delegations":[],     
            "PSDelegation": "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances"       
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Why do I need to do this ?

There is a limitation/possible bug within bicep, and one way that I have tested which gets around the problem is to alter a subnet via AZ cli by running the code below.

```
az network vnet subnet update \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name mySubnet \
    --vnet-name myVNet \
    --delegations Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances
```

The flow will work like this.

1. Write a Ps file which accepts a resource group as a parameter.
2. Check if the resource group exists, if it does proceed. If it doesnt throw an error.
3. Look in the json file for array sections that have a    `PSDelegation` value If there is a value Check if the vnet in the loop above exists in the RG (resource group)
4. If the vnet exists, check if the subnet exists, if it does proceed, if not throw an error.
5. Now edit the subnet by running the snippet of code below.

   az network vnet subnet update 
   --resource-group myResourceGroup 
   --name mySubnet 
   --vnet-name myVNet 
   --delegations Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances

Comment: What do you want to do with this data once you've extracted it? Export it to a separate JSON document? Export it to CSV? Use it as input for another command/script?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen I edited the question explaining what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited per comment and OP's edit:**

Once you have your json, you can access the subnetArray using `value`, then access fields in `$record` like you would expect.

```
# parameter declaration, resource group declaration...
# check for existence also goes here
$myResourceGroup = 'foo'

# get your json and make sure vNet+subnet exist
$json = Get-Content '.\json_file.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
if ($json.parameters.psobject.properties.name -contains 'vNetArray' -and -not $json.parameters.psobject.properties.name -contains 'subnetArray'){
    throw 'subnetArray not found!'
}

# edit the subnet 
foreach ($record in $json.parameters.subnetArray.value) {
    if ($record.PSDelegation){
      $mySubnet = $record.subnetName
      $myVNet = $record.vNetName
      & az network vnet subnet update --resource-group $myResourceGroup --name $mySubnet --vnet-name $myVNet --delegations Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right! Updating my answer to reflect this and OP's new edit.

Comment: Cheers, very nice!